# Will updating working copy of TortoiseSVN from 1.7 to 1.8 cause an issue for others working in the same repository using 1.7?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I'm migrating from a HD to an SSD. I was using TortoiseSVN 1.7 on the HD for a project that has multiple coders using the same repository.

I installed TSVN 1.8 on the SSD, and am attempting to use it with the project's old-format working copy. It asks me to upgrade the format to 1.8, but I'm wondering if that permanent change is going to make its way back into the repository when I do my next checkin, and if that is going to cause problems for other coders not using the new format.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No. Internal *local* changes of WC structure doesn't reflected in *remote* repository:  there are only a few compatibility issues between server- and client-side versions of SVN

Answer (score 0):

LazyBadger is correct but a few more details are worth noting:

- Be aware of the distinction of the SVN server vs the SVN client; TSVN is a client, existing separately on the machine of each developer. Thus, this question is addressing upgrading a client specifically.
- When it asks you to upgrade the format to 1.8, it is talking about the infrastructure of your working copy, the way it stores and manages files on your box. That infrastructure is local to your machine; it is not reflected on the server.
- However, it is **not** a general rule that you can always upgrade a client and remain compatible, but moving from TSVN 1.7 to TSVN 1.8 does, in fact, maintain compatibility.
- Ultimately to answer this question each time you are considering an upgrade, have a look at the TortoiseSVN release notes--for 1.8 they are [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.8_releasenotes.html#compatibility). In there you will see that it specifically states that "*Older clients and servers interoperate transparently with 1.8 servers and clients.*"

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping this was the case, and couldn't see any reason why they would introduce an incompatibility, but it was important for me to not make an assumption, given the scope of the project.

Comment: @grayman: Consider marking this as the accepted answer if it completely answers your question; that way anyone else landing on this page will know that this is useful information and not leading them astray :-)